# Man and woman travelling through parallel universe?

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

The only things about this book I can remember is there is male and female main characters journeying through an alternate/parallel universe.  Along the way they meet various people, though the only character I can remember is named "Rupert of Murdoch" of some alternate spelling with sounds like that.  Some of the names are a play on real-life people's names.

It would have been a 1990s maybe late 80s book, and I think the author was male.

I used to read this book often when I was younger but the title has slipped my mind :p

Comment: What language? English?

Comment: Yes it was in English.

Comment: The publishing date doesn't match, but it sounds a little like the "Otherland" series by Tad Williams - I don't remember a character names "Rupert of Murdoch" but there were many similar plays upon the names of real world personalities.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I read some Tad Williams years ago but not the one I'm looking for.  Now I think about it more this book would have been A Young Adult fiction so aimed more toward teenagers.

Answer (score 3):

No Rupert of Murdoch, but how about [Job](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345316509) by Robert Heinlein.  The protagonist and his female friend get switched through alternate universes as a parody of the Book of Job.

Comment: No, but thanks.

Comment: I think the cover was mostly blue and the author's surname started with the 1st third of the alphabet as I remember where the book was physically in the library.