# Parallel universes book loosely based on the Book of Job. Main character moves from universe to universe unwillingly

Tags: story-identification, books

24 years ago, I read a fiction book based loosely on the book of Job.  I can remember the main character was sent to parallel universes, in which he stayed the same person, but had to start over again each time, and took to wearing a gold necklace, so that he could pawn/sell each time to get him set up.

Comment: I've read the Book of Job and I don't remember anything about parallel universes.

Comment: Possibly the same book (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32801/man-and-woman-travelling-through-parallel-universe?rq=1)?

Comment: Oh, I vaguely remember this one - the back of the book mentioned an old safety razor and the end puts some very novel twists on religion.

Answer (score 43):

Could this be [JOB: A Comedy of Justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job:_A_Comedy_of_Justice) by Robert Heinlein (from 1984)? The story is described as being loosely based on the Book of Job.

> Whenever they manage to make some stake, an inconveniently timed
>   change into a new alternate reality throws them off their stride
>   (once, the money they earned is left behind in another reality; in
>   another case, the paper money earned in a Mexico which is an empire is
>   worthless in another Mexico which is a republic). **These repeated
>   misfortunes, clearly effected by some malevolent entity, make the hero
>   identify with the Biblical Job.**

The main character shifts between alternate worlds and tries, where possible, to get hold of hard currency (gold and silver) as it's much more useful than paper money. No mention of necklaces though.

> *Example: I had figured out that, while paper money was never any good
>   after a world change, hard money, gold and silver, would somehow be
>   negotiable, as bullion if not coin. So, when I got a chance to lay
>   hands on hard money, I was stingy with it and refused to take paper
>   money in change for hard money.*

Comment: Unrelated to what it is, but this is probably my least favorite Heinlein novel.

Comment: @ZeissIkon ditto, but towards the end of his life it was a race to the bottom...

Comment: And yet, *Friday* and *To Sail Beyond the Sunset* were pretty good.  In my opinion, at least.